# Android GCM receive not working

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to set up push notifications in an app for the first time. I think the server side is OK (the message send to google comes back with status code 200, and I see a success result in the response body).
But the device never does anything :(

Manifest is set as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.package" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/appName"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="my.package.activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="my.package" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name=my.package.NotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And the NotificationListenerService is like this:

```
public class NotificationListenerService extends GcmListenerService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d("MyApp", "message);

        Notification.ShowNotification("test", getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

I *think* that's all I need according to https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client (asides from the stuff to handle reset tokens which I've not added yet. My token registration seems to work as I can see the token in the dev console data store.)

I've tried looking at logcat but nothing obvious seems to appear. Do I need to "start" the service in some way? The documentation suggests not... I'm obviously missing something fundamental though!

Answer (score 0):

When you send a message, your server normally gets a message_id as a response. Using the diagnostics tool with the message_id could be useful to make sure that GCM correctly relayed the message.

Is Google Play Services up-to-date on your device ?